# entity framework add data to multible tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mariadb

for my current project i would like to add new data from an ObservableCollection. The Collection contains a big object with all the attributes of the three tables i use. I use the Entity Framework 5.0 in Visual Studio 2015, the newest version of MariaDB and the newest version of the mysql-connector.
Unfortunately i haven´t found an example for multiple tables; only for one.
So i tried this, but it throws always an DbEntityValidationException in the EntityFramework.dll:

```
foreach(ZeichnungInDB zeichnungInDB in zeichnungen)
        {
            zeichnungInDB.Volante_Index = getVolCountByDrawingNumber(zeichnungInDB.Zeichnungsnummer)+1;
            using (DMSContext db = new  DMSContext())
            {
                var zeichnung = new zeichnung()
                {
                    Zeichnung_ID = zeichnungInDB.Dateiname + "_" + zeichnungInDB.Index + "_VOL_" + zeichnungInDB.Volante_Index + "_" + new DateTime().ToShortDateString(),
                    Baugruppe = zeichnungInDB.Baugruppe,
                    Baugruppe_Hauptzeichnung = zeichnungInDB.Baugruppe_Hauptzeichnung,
                    Zeichnungsnummer = zeichnungInDB.Zeichnungsnummer,
                    Index = zeichnungInDB.Index,
                    Dateiname_Org = zeichnungInDB.Dateiname,
                    Aenderung_Ext = zeichnungInDB.Aenderung_Ext,
                    Aenderung_Int = "AE_" + zeichnungInDB.Projektnummer + new DateTime(),
                    Dokumententyp = zeichnungInDB.DokumentenTyp,
                    Dateiendung = zeichnungInDB.Extension,
                    Volante_Index = zeichnungInDB.Volante_Index,
                    MMS_Sachmerkmal = zeichnungInDB.Mms_Sachmerkmal,
                    Status = zeichnungInDB.Status,
                    Aenderung_Bemerkung_Txt = zeichnungInDB.Aenderung_Bemerkung_Text,
                    Einzel_Bemerkung_Txt = zeichnungInDB.Einzel_Bemerkung,
                    Ahang_Link = zeichnungInDB.Anhang_Link,
                    Einzel_Link = zeichnungInDB.Einzel_Link,
                };

                var projekt = new projekt()
                {
                    Projektnummer = zeichnungInDB.Projektnummer,
                };

                var tag = new tag()
                {
                    Tag1 = zeichnungInDB.Tag,
                };

                //var zeichnung = new zeichnung();
                //zeichnung.

                db.zeichnungs.Add(zeichnung);
                db.projekts.Add(projekt);
                db.tags.Add(tag);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I know that the code is not that performant. But i just want that it works. The best way would be just to give the database the collection in one step or how to insert the new data in one database access but i dont know that works because i quit my job after finishing my education for three years now.
It would be very helpful if someone has an answer for my problem.

Cheers,
Only3lue

Comment: What is the exact exception? Please add the stack.

Comment: can you show the models code ?

Comment: okey i found the mistake in the database. but can i code this more perfomant then it is right now?

Comment: Change the `using` with the `foreach` statement, so that you only have to open a DB connection once. In addition only one call (after the foreach) to db.Save() is enough since you do not create references between the data rows.

Comment: okey thanks. but i see that the only thing that dont works like i thought it would work are the referneces between the tables. i thought that the entity will handle the references for itself. for example when i add the new drawing object to the database which is included in a specific project, the database generates a new project in the database abd dont just build the reference. so, is there a method for that or have i to hard code the references. in the ...edmx file the tables are already linked with references.

Comment: so i made the changes with the using, oreach and the db.SaveChanges(). acutally im sitting on the problem, that when i insert the new data it throws a DbUpdateEntityException which is telling me, that it trys to create an object in the database with the same primary key and that dont work. i guess he is trying to create a new project with the same projectnumber but that already exists. so how can i stop this, that it checks if the project already exists and dont try to create an new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to catch the DbEntityValidationException and see which input throw the exception :

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    Exception raise = dbEx;
    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", 
            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
            validationError.ErrorMessage);
            // raise a new exception nesting
            // the current instance as InnerException
            raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
        }
    }
    throw raise;
}
```

Comment: okey, for itself it throws InvalidOperationException.
But i dont know if u can read German it tells:
MMS.zeichnung:Das Feld "Zeichnung_ID" muss ein Zeichenfolgen- oder Arraytyp mit einer maximalen Länge von 50 sein.

Comment: @Only3lue Add the stacktrace to your question. This is an english platform.

Comment: Look like that "Zeichnung_ID" should be a string limited to 50 characters

Comment: yeah i updated the string limitation and now it works! ty
but can i code this more perfomant then it is right now?

Comment: You code look fine for me to store data in your tables

Comment: i have a problem now with the entites. it seems that it is trying to create now the same project by insert even it exists. because it tells me that he cant match the match the zeichnung table with the project table, because two or more objects have the same primary key. so it seems that it trys to add a new project with the same number, too, even it already exists. the entity is: project has many drawings and drawing has only one project. this is correct but i dont undertsand why it is trying to create a new project with the same number when its not declared like that.